# How to get a response key into the URL, Google Apps Script

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth-2.0, request

I need to get the permission to access to specific URL, but before that I need to get the `responseKey`, and the way to get the `responseKey` is to access to this URL in the browser: `https://api.getgo.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id={consumerKey}&response_type=code`. After accessing
it contains the responseKey what I need. It will look something like: `http://example.com/oauthreturn/?code={responseKey}`. The question is how I can get the `responseKey` in code in google-apps-scrpits.
This what i wrote:

```
function myFunction() {
  var client_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  var url ="https://api.getgo.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id="+client_id+"&response_type=code";
  var resp =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
}
```

but I get a HTML code response

Answer (score 2):

In your code `var resp =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` will create a [HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response.html) object. First, you will want to know if the response code is [`200 OK`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.1). To gather that information you should use [`getResponseCode()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response.html#getresponsecode) and check if it equals to `200`. If that is the case, then you must parse the code. To do that you can first use [`getContentText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getcontenttext) and after that [`parse()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#work_with_json). One example implementation, that is compatible with your code, can be this one:

```
if (resp.getResponseCode() == 200) {
  var results = JSON.parse(resp.getContentText());
}
```

You can then access to the data referring to that variable and the name of the parameter. For example, you could use `results.code`, `results.token`… If this explanation doesn't clarify your question, please ask me again for further help.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when i call this line  `var results = JSON.parse(resp.getContentText());` I get an error syntax : **SyntaxError: Unexpected token: <**. You know why?

Comment: that error means that the JSON parser is encountering a strange symbol («*<*» in this case). Try to substitute that line to `var results = resp.getContentText();` If that doesn't work, please log [ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logdata ] both `Logger.log(JSON.parse(resp.getContentText()))` and `Logger.log(resp.getContentText())` so we all can see where the unexpected token is found.

Comment: I trying what you told me and  I get a HTML code, but what I need to recive is the responseKey. Here is the [docs](https://goto-developer.logmeininc.com/how-get-access-token-and-organizer-key)